# How to connect frontend (Angular) with backend of a local hyperledger fabric fabcar sample v2.2?

Tags: angular, frontend, hyperledger-fabric, backend, hyperledger

I really hope for some help because I don't have a lot of experience in these areas.

Basically, it's about the simple local connection of frontend and backend using the **fabcar** example of the new hyperledger fabric version **2.2.1**.

I installed all the prerequisites and installed the samples, binaries and docker images.

If I start the **startFabric.sh** inside /fabric-samples/fabcar in the terminal and then run the script in /fabric-samples/fabcar/go with **go run fabcar.go**, I got e.g. the results of QueryAll.

My question now, how do I get these results that are displayed to me in the terminal, simply mapped onto a local UI (Angular)?

I found a couple of tutorials for older versions or with other tools like chainstack. Is there someone who could give me a **step-by-step guideline** or good **tutorials** for beginners? Because I don't have that much experience with for example nodejs express server, REST API, Socket.io or the Hyperledger Node SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create API to connect Hyperledger Fabric network and perform operation. Hyperledger has provided a [SDK for Node](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/) for this purpose which helps to create REST APIs and it can be used in any front end application. There is also a [SDK for JAVA](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/).

Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@kctheservant/rework-an-implementation-of-api-server-for-hyperledger-fabric-network-fabric-v2-2-a747884ce3dc) from KC Tam that will help you to do it easily, Let me know if you need any further assistance, Good luck.

Comment: the link from KC Team is great but he worked with AWS EC2... can i do it locally (localhost) with nodejs express server? Or a ubuntu server with VirtualBox?

Comment: Yes it can be done in the same way, it will perfectly fine, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: The API works fine now. But I don't know how to bind the single properties like model, owner etc. into textfileds. Any suggestion?